# Does lightsail instance also includes dbms?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I am implementing a very basic dynamic website for a school, where a parent will be able to see the fee due and child's attendance. This service will have on average 30 users per day.

I am exploring different platforms which are cost effective and easy to develop.

Does AWS Lightsail includes dbms(relational or nosql) or I will have to use an RDS instance as well(that will hike the price).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you can check this [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-managed-databases-for-amazon-lightsail/) from AWS.

**Managed Databases**

> Today we are making Lightsail even more useful by giving you the
>   ability to create a managed database with a couple of clicks. This has
>   been one of our top customer requests and I am happy to be able to
>   share this news.
>
> This feature is going to be of interest to a very wide range of
>   current and future Lightsail users, including students, independent
>   developers, entrepreneurs, and IT managers. We’ve addressed the most
>   common and complex issues that arise when setting up and running a
>   database. As you will soon see, we have simplified and fine-tuned the
>   process of choosing, launching, securing, accessing, monitoring, and
>   maintaining a database!

But you have few users montly basis as just 30 users as you said, I will suggest to go with LAMP if you are using php

> LAMP with PHP 7.x certified by Bitnami greatly simplifies the
>   development and deployment of PHP applications. It includes the latest
>   versions of PHP 7.x, Apache and MySQL together with phpMyAdmin and
>   popular PHP frameworks Zend, Symfony, CodeIgniter, CakePHP, Smarty,
>   and Laravel.

Or if you are using nodejs then with **NoSQL** you can try with MEAN stack.

> MEAN certified by Bitnami provides a complete production environment
>   for MongoDB and Node.js applications. It includes the latest stable
>   release of MongoDB, Express, Angular and Node.js. Apart from these
>   core components, it also includes the latest versions of Apache, Git,
>   PHP and RockMongo.

Here is screenshot from **APP+OS**
[image]

[lightsail-DB-and-instance](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/webapp/home/instances)

Comment: Are you suggesting to create local db instance in the linux rather than using managed database?

Comment: If yes, will it underperform in terms of latency. Will it suffer cold start latency after every few hours of being inactive?

Comment: If the data is critical and should be backed up automatically then go for managed instances with just 15$per month that can fulfill your requirements

Comment: Yes if the data is not critical then fine to go with existing stack

Comment: Can I use dynamodb with lightsail?

Comment: I didn't explore that but if you click on the link give you'll see the list